# knowing if need for smartcard on certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, smartcard

I have a X509Certificate2 instance.

What I want is to know if the private key lives in hardware (usually smartcard)
without Windows popping up a message such as "please insert smartcard".

My current solution is this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = myX509Instance.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider; // problem here
if(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice)
{
     // needs for some hardware..
}
```

The problem is that the above cast will create a modal windows message which asks the user to inert a smart card.

Is there any way to accomplish my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Mr. Bit, try to format your questions as well as possible, reread your questions, perform some grammar checking, and use common tags. Even though you are probably using C# version 4, you are not asking a question that relates to that particular version.